# div id not defined in Firefox (javascript console) - OK in IE & Chrome

Tags: javascript

I've done a good amount of research here on Stack Overflow and I've tried many of the suggestions of users that have run into the same problem, but have had no luck.

I have this piece of javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ActivateTab(strTabName){
    switch (strTabName){
        case "EmployeeInfo":
            divEmployeeInfo.className = "panelActive";
            divCoverageTypes.className = "panelHidden";
        break;
        case "CoverageTypes":
            divEmployeeInfo.className = "panelHidden";
            divCoverageTypes.className = "panelActive";

        break;
    }
}
```

Here is where it is called:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="2">
<tr>
    <td align="center" id="tdEmployeeInfo" onClick="ActivateTab('EmployeeInfo')" class="tabActive">Employee Information &amp; Demographic Changes </td>
    <td align="center" id="tdCoverageTypes" onClick="ActivateTab('CoverageTypes')" class="tabItem"><p>Change, Add or Delete Coverage</p></td>
    <td align="center" id="tdSpouseOrPartner" onClick="ActivateTab('SpouseOrPartner')" class="tabItem">Change, Add or Delete Spouse or Domestic Partner</td>
    <td align="center" id="tdDependent" onClick="ActivateTab('Dependent')" class="tabItem">Change, Add or Delete Dependent</td>
</tr>
```

With the corresponding html:

```
<div id="divEmployeeInfo" class="panelActive">
<input type="hidden" id="SectionTab_EmployeeInfo" name="SectionTab_EmployeeInfo" value="Employee Information">
```

Can anyone lend a seconds set of eyes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to use an element ID as a Javascript variable.
This is a non-standard IE extension that doesn't work in actual browsers.

Instead, call `document.getElementById` to get the DOM element with the given ID:

```
document.getElementById("divEmployeeInfo").className = "panelActive";
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to SLaks answer you can update your js to be more readable:

```
var divEmployeeInfo = null;
var divCoverageTypes = null;

function Initialize() {
    if (divEmployeeInfo == null) {
        divEmployeeInfo = document.getElementById("divEmployeeInfo");
        divCoverageTypes = document.getElementById("divCoverageTypes");
    }
}

function ActivateTab(tab) {
    Initialize();

    divEmployeeInfo.className = GetClass("EmployeeInfo", tab);
    divCoverageTypes.className = GetClass("CoverageTypes", tab);
}

function GetClass(key, selected) {
    return key == selected ? "panelActive" : "panelHidden";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make use of jQuery you can modify the elements classes like:

```
$('#divEmployeeInfo').addClass('panelActive');
$('#divCoverageTypes').removeClass('panelActive');
```

You could also move your click handling out of the HTML like this:

```
$('#tdEmployeeInfo').click(function() {
    $('#divEmployeeInfo').addClass('panelActive');
    $('#divCoverageTypes').removeClass('panelActive');
});
```